# How can Electron change the color of tray based on the desktop background on MacOS?

Tags: electron

I want to listen the event of changing desktop background and change the color of tray.

```js
nativeTheme.on('updated', () => {
  this.setLocaTheme();
});
```

this snippet only just listen the event of change the dark mode setting.

How can Electron change the color of tray based on the desktop background on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

Template images consist of black and an alpha channel. Template images are not intended to be used as standalone images and are usually mixed with other content to create the desired final appearance.

The most common case is to use template images for a menu bar icon, so it can adapt to both light and dark menu bars.

```
xxxTemplate.png
xxxTemplate@2x.png
```